# Twitter API not working in WIMP server environment

Tags: jquery, twitter, lamp, wimp

This site is set up in a WIMP environment and does NOT work:

http://www.xsp.com/

This is the test site set up in a LAMP environment and DOES work:

http://www.bigideaadv.com/xsp_OLD/BACKUP/index2.php

Using Remy Sharp's twitter plugin: http://code.google.com/p/twitterjs/downloads/list and his smooth marquee for a nicer display: http://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee/

Anyone have any thoughts on why this is causing errors on the live site?

Comment: Would you know where these are located on a Windows server?

Comment: in your WIMP installation folder somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tips Rene. I think the issue was with some of code formatting. I reinspected it all and eventually got it working smoothly.